# Short network peaks on AWS EC2 instances

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services

From time to time I'm seeing on different AWS instances with short network peaks, that lead to up to 1 second instance unavailability. Sometimes this peaks happened at the same time for AWS instances in different VPC, but in same region, AZ and account.

screenshots:

[cloudwatch metrics for one instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jlT1.png)

[cloudwatch metrics of another instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kXnt.png)

What can cause this?

Comment: Do you have a cron of some sort running?

Comment: nope, it is pure ubuntu instances

Comment: So there's nothing installed on them except the base AMI?

Comment: I have docker on both instances, on one I have redis with redis-sentinel, you can notice that sentinels marked redis on this instance as failed and any network activity was stopped.

Comment: That's a lot more than a "pure" Ubuntu instance. I'm not sure how I "can notice than sentinels marked redis" anything - Redis isn't mentioned in your question or the screenshots. You need to provide more details.

Comment: I meant that on second graph you can notice, that traffic stopped to flow after problem peak, and I explained the reason of this behaviour. Not sure which details you want me to provide, this peaks a happened on different types of instances in different time, it happen with redis instance, it happen with rabbitmq instance, it happen with webserver for staging purpose and instance with openvpn client. All this instances are instances with different purpose and looks like this peaks are more related to some general thing like EC2.

Comment: Two things that come to mind are backups (probably not) and automated updates, though I doubt it's either. You should make use of [VPC Flow Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html) to track this down.

Comment: wow, thanks @Tim, I will definitely try VPC Flow Logs to dig into traffic flow.